# Give AWS lambda access to PostgreSQL on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a PostgreSQL instance running on an EC2 instance and I've set up this instance security group to give me access from my IP.
How can I do the same for a Lambda endpoint?
I've included the lambda security group in the EC2 security group (using the same strategy I did for my IP address), but it's not working. I'm getting the error message: Can't reach the database at IP XXXX
What's the missing step here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should configure the AWS Lambda function to **connect to the same VPC as the Amazon EC2 instance**, then configure the security groups as:

- One **security group on the Lambda function** (`Lambda-SG`) with Outbound rules permitting All Outbound traffic
- One **security group on the EC2 instance** that is running PostgreSQL (`DB-SG`) with Inbound rules that permit access on port 5432 from `Lambda-SG`

That is, `DB-SG` should specifically reference `Lambda-SG`. This will permit the Lambda function access to the EC2 instance, regardless of which IP address the Lambda function is using.

Alternatively, you could choose to *not* connect the Lambda function to the VPC, in which case the connection request would come in from the Internet. However, I don't think that there is a fixed range of addresses used by Lambda (it is not listed on [AWS IP address ranges - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)), so it would not be possible to restrict access.

Comment: ty guys, this solution was simples and resolve all problem for me